# Href Anchor Text - Open Chat Widget

Tags: html, anchor, href

I am using this anchor text to open the Hubspot widget `<a href="#hs-chat-open" class="my-chat">Open chat</a>` which works fine.

However, if the user closes the chat widget and clicks on the link again it doesn't open anymore. I suppose this is a bug with the browser and the way anchor links are handled, is there another way around this without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can easily reopen the widget just by calling the open function using javascript

```js
   window.HubSpotConversations.widget.open();
```